# Concrete Sobject error during compiling

Tags: apex

When i compile my program i get an error such that :Initial field of expression must be concrete sobject.Can any one help me to understand about that problem.

Comment: Could you please post the whole error message?

Comment: Are you trying to create a page with standard controller?

Comment: I dont have the code which has generated this error ,previously i had this issue  but since i changed that entire code the error did not occur.But i want to about the nature of that error

Answer (score 4):

This usually means you have used the dot notation where it is not appropriate.  For example, if you declare an opportunity variable and then inadvertently use the opportunity sobject rather than the variable name you would see this error:

```
Opportunity opp=new Opportunity();
Opportunity.Name='Test';   // error would occur on this line
```

There's a good explanation of how the dot notation is parsed at:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_namespace_precedence.htm